# Bar Button Item not correctly aligned

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, vertical-alignment, uibarbuttonitem

I have an issue with my navigation bar, the UIBarButtonItem is not correctly vertically aligned. I don't know why because I'm using a simple UIBarButtonItem and not a custom view. See my code below and thanks for your help!

```
UIBarButtonItem *newGameItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Game" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(newGame)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newGameItem;
```

[image: Screenshot navigation bar issue]

Comment: That doesn't look like the default font for a standard UIBarButtonItem. Are you modifying any barbutton font properties? Maybe with UIAppearance?

Comment: You're wondering why "new game" is slightly **below** the "board" title?

Comment: Yes I use Avenir Next, but I use this font in another app and there's no issue with the navigation bar.

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:18.0]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-DemiBold" size:18.0]}];

Comment: I would try decreasing the font size.

Comment: It sounds like a font size issue. Just to be clear, is "Board" a `title` or a `titleView`?

Comment: Its dues to padding in the Font itself, you can try use `self.navigationItem.titleView` to set the title..

Comment: Decreasing the font size of UIBarButtonItem from 18 to 16 is resolving the issue.

Comment: i've updated my answer. Mark it as the answer for your question if you don't mind

Comment: because it is the answer to your current question, not the advice to change font :)

Comment: @SebThiebaud Which method did you use from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually there are couple ways to align the bar buttons.
Try to adjust the button title position with this:

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-10, -10) 
                                                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

-10 -10 - just for example

**OR**

you can initialize your `newGameItem` with custom `UIButton`. The custom button is a subclass of UIButton with this method overridden

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)alignmentRectInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, 15.0f); // here you can play with values to align your button properly
}
```

then initialize your `newGameItem`

```
CustomBarButton *button = [CustomBarButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"New game" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake (0, 0, 60, 40);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(newGame) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *newGameItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newGameItem;
```

Comment: Second solution does indeed work, albeit not so elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue: We use custom fonts via `UIAppearance` for both navigation titles and bar button items, and in some cases, the right item was vertically misaligned.

I could easily fix the misalignment by using `[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightItem animated:YES]` instead of the property setter.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a button on the left, I was able to fix it in Xcode 6.3.1: select the button (bar button item) right column tab "ruler" inset image Top value: -54 instead of 0.
Note that: my device is an iPhone4 with iOS 7, the button was perfectly in place in Xcode and misplaced on the device, now it is in place on the device and misplaced in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not much you can do about `UIBarButtonItem` vertical spacing. I believe you'll have to either increase the font size of your title on the `UINavigationBar` (you can do this with `UIAppearance` also), or decrease the font size of your `UIBarButtonItem`.