# Right bar button item not aligned vertically

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem, ios7.1, rightbarbuttonitem

I am setting a rightbarbuttonitem in from a viewController using the following code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(saveDetails)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

It is appearing as shown in the image:

[image: navigationitem]

As you can see, the button which appears is not vertically aligned with either th leftbuttonitem or the title.

I also tried adjusting the alignment using the code mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23547566/2043580):

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -10) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But this removes the custom font and moves the button even higher.

[image: navigation item with adjustment]

How can I set a rightbarbuttonitem which is aligned AND maintains the custom font set using the UIAppearance proxy?

EDIT:

I even tried using

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(saveDetails)];
```

but the result is exactly as shown in the first image.

UPDATE (Sep 20):

It seems that I will have to go with Alexander's answer, anybody with a cleaner solution?

Comment: Using systemBarButtonItem with `UIBarButtonSystemItemSave` isn't in your choices?

Comment: Well, I found out the code for that after posting the question. However, it is practically the same as my original code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the next variant:

```
UIButton *saveButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 20)];
[saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveDetails) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[saveButton setTitle: @"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[saveButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 0, 0)];
UIBarButtonItem *item =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:saveButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

Comment: I did, and the results are better. This will be my last resort, as it will take some time adjusting the button to it's right position.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answer but didn't seem to work.

The solution for me was adding `UIButton` as `UIBarButtonItem`. If it sounds confusing, just drag a `UIButton` from Interface Builder to the position of `Left` or `RightBarButtonItem` on the `navigationBar` in your `storyboard`.

Hope it helps.