# left bar button item alignment - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

i can't get my left bar button item to align vertically. Here is my current code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var image = UIImage(named: "pinImage")
    image = image?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleMapView))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "+", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(createTrip))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Nunito", size: 48)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(r: 123, g: 230, b: 200)], for: UIControlState.normal)
}
```

I have tried using :

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(4, for: .default)
```

but I can't get my vertical position to change. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546161/bar-button-item-not-correctly-aligned

Comment: I have tried this as well and this didn't help

Comment: maybe you can use `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 5, right: 10)` to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot align them, because they go with your navigationBar. However, you can get that, by adding subview, and aligning your items in subview. Or another way is to use UIEdgeInsets